# Как разместить Button под ListView?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Есть компонент `ListView`. Он развернут на весь экран. Но внизу экрана надо разместить кнопки так, чтобы `ListView` ее не перекрывал. Что надо поменять в разметке?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvBaseCoord"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btOk"
        android:text="Ok"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btCancel"
        android:text="Отмена"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

И еще, можно ли у `ListView` показать скроллинг справа?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте атрибут `android:layout_weight`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvBaseCoord"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btOk"
            android:text="Ok"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btCancel"
            android:text="Отмена"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

У Вас еще `ListView` зачем-то обернут в `LinearLayout`, я его убрал.

По поводу скроллбара:

```
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

Comment: Скролбар почему то не показывается.

Comment: @kaaa, А если так `android:fadeScrollbars="false"`?

Comment: После добавления этих строк ListView не отображается. android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"

Comment: @kaaa, Замените весь Ваш `xml` на тот, который в ответе.

Comment: Заработало, но скролбар такой тонкий, что за него не схватиться. Можно как-то его увеличить. Он мне и нужен только потому, что список оч.большой.

Comment: @kaaa, `android:scrollbarSize="50dip"`.

Comment: не помогло. пока тонкий.

Comment: @kaaa, Вообще говоря, я бы посоветовал Вам заменить `ListView` на `RecyclerView`, ибо последний легче кастомизируется.

Comment: А так, можете попробовать еще `android:fastScrollEnabled="true"`.

Comment: Супер! Все как хотел получилось!